# Export Hive Query Results

Tags: hive, hiveql, hue

I'm new to `hive` and could use some tips.

I'm trying to export query results from `hive` as a `csv`.  When I try to pipe them out of CLI like:

```
hive -e 'select * from table'>OutPut.txt
```

I get a text file that has all the records but doesn't have the column headers.  Does anyone have a tip for how to export the query results with the column headers, to a `csv` file?

If I run the query in hue, and then download the results as a `csv` I get a `csv` with the column headers but no records.  If anyone has a tip on how to download query results from hue with records and column headers, I would greatly appreciate it too.

Answer (score 5):

To export the column headers, you need to set the following in the `hiverc` file:

`set hive.cli.print.header=true;`

To get just the headers into a file, you could try the following:

`hive -e 'set hive.cli.print.header=true; SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME LIMIT 0;' > /file_path/file_name.txt`

Comment: Hi Visakh, thanks for getting back to me on this.  Your suggestion worked great for getting the column headers included along with the data, as a text file.  Can you suggest how I could add 'c' as a delimiter for the columns, to the exported data?

Comment: I would suggest processing the `file_name.txt` using any `Unix` utility such as `sed` or `awk` to add the delimiters for the column names.

Comment: Hi i did the same way, but in the result i am getting column names along with table names for each column name

Comment: I want oly the column names to come

Answer (score 0):

Having the column header but missing data is a known issue: [HUE-544](https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-544)

The workaround is to use Hue 3 or more or switch to HiveServer2 (recommended starting from [CDH4.6](http://gethue.com/hadoop-tutorial-hive-query-editor-with-hiveserver2-and/)).